# Inserting an OracleClob array

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess

For my .NET project i really need to be able to insert an array of Clob's into an Oracle Db, using the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess lib.

```
byte[] newval = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("Testyy");
                    var clob = new OracleClob(connection);
                    var clobList = new List<OracleClob>() { clob, clob };
                    clob.Write(newval, 0, newval.Length);

                    var longText = new OracleParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = "p_tc_long_text",
                        OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Clob,
                        CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray,
                        Value = clobList.ToArray(),
                        Size = clobList.Count,
                    };

                    command.Parameters.Add(longText);
```

After execution of the command i get the Oracle Error:

ORA-03120: two-task conversion routine: integer overflow.

Comment: What is the code of the procedure? Where in the procedure does the error occur (what is the full text of the error message)? Does the procedure work if you change the datatype to an associative array of `VARCHAR2` and pass smaller strings (i.e. can you eliminate CLOBs as the issue)? Have you tried passing two different CLOBs, rather than two CLOBs that are the same object? (The last one might not make a difference but there might be a weird issue with reading the same data twice).

Comment: Also, what is `longText`? Are you sure the error is occurring with the associative array and not with that parameter?

Comment: No i can not eliminate the Cob, thats the point of the question in the first place,

Comment: No i' m not posting the entire code, because i filterd out the boilerplate that is not relevant

Comment: You have misinterpreted what I am saying - change the data type to an associative array of `VARCHAR2` and see if the error still exists. If it does then CLOBs are not the source of the error. If the error disappears then the issue is using CLOBs and not elsewhere in the procedure.

Comment: You do not need to post the entire code but you do need to give a [MCVE] and this includes a minimal version of the PL/SQL code that is being invoked and the full error message so that we can replicate and debug the issue. If you cannot provide the minimal required information for us to help you then we cannot help you.

Comment: after a long search I figured out the issue, short answer, its not supported

Comment: This whas an absolutely acceptable question, and im tired of this Stackoverflow community members downvoting just because it feels good to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported

ODP.NET supports binding parameters of PL/SQL Associative Arrays which contain the following data types.

- BINARY_FLOAT
- CHAR
- DATE
- NCHAR
- NUMBER
- NVARCHAR2
- RAW
- ROWID
- UROWID
- VARCHAR2